# Mouse interaction issues on QSlider with QLabel overlay

Tags: python, qt, overlay, pyside

I am pretty new to Qt/PySide and trying to figure out a way to overlay a `QLabel` onto a `QSlider` without loosing mouse events interactivity. Currently using the `QStackedLayout` I am unable to trigger them correctly with the label on top, and it doesn't even behave when under (the slider doesn't interpolate, jumps from min to max).

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class CustomSlider(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, minVal=0.0, maxVal=1.0, default=0.0):
        super(CustomSlider, self).__init__()

        self.slider = QtGui.QSlider()
        self.slider.setRange(0.0, 1.0)
        self.slider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setStyleSheet("""
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {
                background: black;
                height: 40px;
            }

            QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
                background: grey;
                height: 40px;
            }

            QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
                background: black;
                height: 40px;
            }""")

        self.overlay = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.overlay.setText("LABEL")
        self.overlay.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.overlay.setStyleSheet("""QLabel{font: bold 18px;}""")

        self.layout = QtGui.QStackedLayout()
        self.layout.setStackingMode(QtGui.QStackedLayout.StackAll)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.overlay)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The slider jumps from 0 to 1 because it only accepts integer values. If, for example, you set the maximum to 100, you'll find it works.

As for stacking, you can always pass the events through:

```
class CustomSlider(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, minVal=0.0, maxVal=1.0, default=0.0):
        super(CustomSlider, self).__init__()

        self.slider = QtGui.QSlider()
        self.slider.setRange(0.0, 100.0)  # <--
        self.slider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setStyleSheet("""
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {
                background: black;
                height: 40px;
            }

            QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
                background: grey;
                height: 40px;
            }

            QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
                background: black;
                height: 40px;
            }""")
        self.overlay = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.overlay.setText("LABEL")
        self.overlay.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.overlay.setStyleSheet("""QLabel{font: bold 18px;color:red;}""")
        self.overlay.mousePressEvent = self.slider.mousePressEvent     # <--
        self.overlay.mouseReleaseEvent = self.slider.mouseReleaseEvent # <--
        self.layout = QtGui.QStackedLayout()
        self.layout.setStackingMode(QtGui.QStackedLayout.StackAll)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.overlay)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```